# Zend create a model with columns names that have spacing

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework

I have a MS  SQL Server db that has tables and column names that contain spaces. How do I go around modeling this. In a model class How would I put the column name if it has a space? Below is my dbtable

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_PurchInvHeader extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{

    protected $_name = 'Spectrum Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header';


}
```

the table is called `Spectrum Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header`. In this table there are many fields with spaces. I just need to fetch all the records for now.

In SQL Server Management Studio the following query works

```
SELECT * from [Navision].[dbo].[Spectrum Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header]
```

Comment: `I have a MS SQL Server db that has tables and column names that contain spaces` if (and only if) you inherited this mess, then my heart go out to you.

Comment: It is MS Dynamics Navision software, complete utter mess. I cannot rename tables.

Comment: No I am still trying to get my pdo dblib connection to work

Answer (score 1):

You may try enquoting your field/column names with "`" . It should normally help distinct the field names from special words and word combinations.

Comment: Updated question with example

Comment: in sql server `[` and `]` are used to escape names and not `\``, as shown in the edited question

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make some views with better names without spaces?

If you can't create them directly in the MS Dynamics Navision database, then create a new database on the same server. Then link that new database to the MS Dynamics Navision database.  Then (in your new database) create all the views, function, and stored procedures, etc. that you need for your zend based application.

Also, views will help your application in the case where the MS Dynamics Navision makes schema changes.

Comment: But how would I input data into these tables then?

Comment: if you make the "new database" and link it to the MS Dynamics Navision database you can query from the new DB like: `SELECT * FROM database.owner.table'.  You can create views in the new DB that refer directly into the MS Dynamics Navision database.  when you make the view, just alter the column names like: `SELECT [bad name here] AS BadNameHere, [silly spaces] AS SillySpaces from [Navision].[dbo].[Spectrum Geo Limited$Purch_ Inv_ Header]`.  Any code you write can now use the view and the new column names that have no spaces.